# BehaviorSubject with defaultValue as Observable

Tags: java, rx-java

How can I provide a default value for `BehaviourSubject` as an `Observable`?

So instead of:

```
// observer will receive the "default", "zero", "one"
BehaviorSubject<Object> subject = BehaviorSubject.create("default");
subject.subscribe(observer);
subject.onNext("zero");
subject.onNext("one");

// observer2 will receive the "one", "two", "three"
subject.subscribe(observer2);
subject.onNext("two");
subject.onNext("three");
```

It would be possible to do:

```
Observable<Object> defaultValueObservable = Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Object>>() {
@Override public Observable<Object> call() {
    // simulate blocking work
    return Observable.just("blocking-default");
   }
})

// observer will receive the "blocking-default", "zero", "one"
BehaviorSubject<Object> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(defaultValueObservable.first());
subject.subscribe(observer);
subject.onNext("zero");
subject.onNext("one");

// observer2 will receive the "one", "two", "three"
subject.subscribe(observer2);
subject.onNext("two");
subject.onNext("three");
```

I understand, that first observer would wait for the calculation of the default value. I'm okay with paying that price.

Basically, I want an in-memory repository. My current implementation idea:

```
public class Repository<T> {
    private final BehaviorSubject<T> subject;

    public Repository() {
        subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    }

    public Observable<T> get() {
        assertUiThread();
        Observable<T> observable = subject.asObservable();
        if (subject.hasValue()) {
            return observable;
        } else {
            return observable.startWith(Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<T>>() {
                @Override public Observable<T> call() {
                    T t = getTfromBlockingSource();
                    return Observable.just(t);
                }
            }));
        }
    }

    public void update(T t) {
        assertUiThread();
        subject.onNext(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I properly understand what you want to accomplish, but why does `subject.startWith(Observable.defer(/*do blocking work here*/)...` not work? You want to have the blocking operation happen when the first subscriber subscribes to the `Subject`? And you don't want to just pass it as a default value because then it would happen when you instantiate the `Subject`? Or is it just that you must get the value "out of" some source `Observable` - in that case, what about `toBlocking`?

Comment: `subject.startWith(defValueObservable)` returns new `Observable` and would always calculate defaultValue even for the second subscriber. While second subscriber for `BehaviorSubject.create("default") would get the latest cached value.

Comment: So you want to calculate the very first value instead of using a constant, okay, but then what will send out the subsequent values and how should it know the first value's computation is finished?

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I think I understand the implementation issue: I was thinking with single item observable, but in general case observable can be infinitive. I have cleared the question to highlight the desired behavior. How can I implement smth like that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your use case, but instead of raw `Object`s, I'd have a `BehaviorSubject<Observable<Object>>` which now can have its first value generated and any subsequent 'raw' value can now be wrapped via `just()`. Then, subscribers can do `.onBackpressureBuffer().concatMap(v -> v)` to get the sequence back in order.

```
BehaviorSubject<Observable<Object>> hiddenSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(
    Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just("default")));
Subject<Observable<Object>, Observable<Object>> subject = 
    hiddenSubject.toSerialized();

Observable<Object> output = subject.onBackpressureBuffer().concatMap(v -> v);

output.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(Observable.just("one"));
subject.onNext(Observable.just("two"));

output.subscribe(System.out::println);
```